# Next.js Types not being infered from getServerSideProps to NextPage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

So the data type from `getServerSideProps` is not being passed to the page.

This is the model:

```js
export type TypeUser = {
  _id?: Types.ObjectId;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  image: string;
  emailVerified: null;
  profileDescription: string;
  imageDownloadFormat: string;
};
```

This is my getServerSideProps

```js
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
  const session = await getServerSession(ctx.req, ctx.res, authOptions);

  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }

  const response = await NextAPIClient.get(`/api/users/by-email/${session.user?.email}`);
  const user: TypeUser = await response.data.data;

  return {
    props: { user },
  };
};
```

and this is the NextPage:

```js
const ProjectsPage: NextPage<InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>> = ({ user }) => {
console.log(user.name);
...
```

So basically, I'm not getting type completion when I do user. something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read on the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#getserversideprops-with-typescript), `GetServerSideProps` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type to which you should give the type of `props` returned by `getServerSideProps`, like so:

```typescript
export type TypeUser = {
  //...
  imageDownloadFormat: string;
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<{ user: TypeUser }> = async (
  ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext
) => {
  // As an example:
  const user: TypeUser = {} as TypeUser;

  return {
    props: { user },
  };
};

const ProjectsPage: NextPage<InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>> = ({
  user,
}) => {
  // This would work now:
  console.log(user.imageDownloadFormat);
  // ...
};
```